# Cannot access attributes of a specific frame in a frameset

Tags: javascript, frames, frameset

When i set the href of a frame using the line:

```
window.parent.frames['page'].location.href = "/page.php?pageID="+pageID+"&windowUID="+windowUID;
```

I am successful, however if i try to access the attributes of that same frame e.g. the src with the following line:

```
alert("src is "+window.parent.frames['page'].src);
```

I get `is undefined error`. What would be the correct syntax for accessing attributes of the frame?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using document.all.page.src retrieves the src of the frame mentioned above

Comment: Can you elaborate ? It's been flagged